# AngularJS two-way binding an input to a decimal number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an HTML 'input' that I'm two-way binding to a decimal number.  The problem is that trying to enter a decimal point does not show up.  But if I 'mouse' the caret to the middle of the digits, then hit '.', then it does insert it - but then it truncates the rest of the test after the numbers.  Decimals key presses really do wierd things in different situations.

```
<table id="readings" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="rdg in vm.readings">
        <td>{{rdg.Value}} {{rdg.Uom}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 100%">
                <input class="form-control" data-ng-model="rdg.ManualValue"
                        placeholder="Manual..." />                                              
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

rdg.ManualValue is a number, which I understand kicks off this extra number validation in AngularJS, regardless of the input 'type'.  But is there a way to get decimals to be 'naturally' entered?  i.e. as you type them?

Bonus question: is there any way to hide the number spinners in any number entry?

Thanks for any advice.
Corey.

Comment: The step="0.01" type="number" attributes will allow for the inputs to accept the decimals just fine, but you would need to bind some sort of custom javascript to the box to have characters added automatically.

Comment: Try this range spinner angular directive. Very simple and easy to implement. http://javabypatel.blogspot.in/2015/12/number-range-spinner-angularjs-directive.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<input class="form-control" data-ng-model="rdg.ManualValue"
                        placeholder="Manual..." step="any" type="number" />`

For hiding number spinner use this css:

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}
```

Comment: I had to add: input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
} and it now works in FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

I use JQuery to setup a keypress event that checks for valid values as they are being entered.The problem with type=number is that it allows you to type in invalid values and then checks for validity later.

```
        jQuery(this).bind (
            "keypress",

            function (e) {

                if( e.which!=8 && e.which!=0 && e.which!=46 && (e.which<48 || 
                         e.which>57) && e.which != 45) { return false;}
                if(e.which != 8 && e.which != 0) {
                    var r = /^-?(\d*)\.{0,1}(\d*)$/ ;
                    var curval ;
                    if(this.value) {
                        curval = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                    } else {
                        curval = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                    }

                    if(!r.test(curval)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```